# Is it possible to have conditional font locks?

Tags: font-lock

For example, I want to use `font-lock-add-keywords` highlight some keywords in source code. But the font lock system would also highlight the same words (anywhere) in the comments/docs/strings part of the source file.

Since there are functions that detects the environment of a given position, e.g. `python-info-docstring-p`, my question is that is it possible to use these kind of functions to have conditional font lock highlights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the font lock system would also highlight the same words (anywhere) in the comments/docs/strings" - No it wouldn't, unless you set `OVERRIDE` in the highlighter (see [`(elisp) Search-based Fontification`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html)).